# How to prepare baby lima beans for this paella recipe?

Tags: substitutions, beans

This [paella recipe](http://www.wholefoodsmarket.com/recipe/stovetop-vegetarian-paella) calls for frozen lima beans, but I only have dried baby lima beans. How should I prepare the lima beans beforehand so that I can treat them as though they were equivalent to the lima beans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really isn't a good substitution. Think of the difference between fresh peas and dried split peas - they are two completely different products. But if you are really set on doing this, simply soak and cook the dried limas like you would any other dried bean, then add the fully cooked lima at the same stage that that recipe calls for the fresh beans.